# Relational Algebra formula for a SQL command

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, relational-algebra

I have the following SQL command:

```
SELECT X,Y,Z FROM A,B,C WHERE A.U=B.U AND A.V=C.V
ORDER BY X,Y
```

I need to write the relational algebra formula for this query. So far I'm at:

```
E =  (π{X,Y,Z}(S{X,Y} ( σ {A.B.U AND A.V=C.V} (A))) * 
     (π{X,Y,Z}(S{X,Y} ( σ {A.B.U AND A.V=C.V} (B))) * 
     (π{X,Y,Z}(S{X,Y} ( σ {A.B.U AND A.V=C.V} (C)))
```

Is this correct ? I am not sure if i have between A, B, C a union or a cartesian product ?

Also I need to transform this expression in an optimal expression. Can anybody give me a step by step example on how to do that?

Thanks !

Comment: You should get the book Applied Mathematics for Database professionals on Apress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like:

```
τ(X,A),(Y,A)(πx,y,z(σa.u=b.u,a.v = c.v(A,B,C)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. The reason is that in relational algebra you can't apply any ordering to the result sets. This means there is no way to do such a thing as an `order by`.

Comment: There is no order by because that is outside the scope of relational algebra, which deals with closure over sets (relations). And of course, sets have no order.  SQL ordering has to do with presentation of the sets (in rows).